# Using 'LIKE' and 'REGEXP' in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I'm trying to use some regex on an expression where I have two conditions on the `WHERE` clause. The pattern I want to capture is 106 followed by any digit followed by a digit that must be either 3 or 4, i.e. `106[0-9][3-4]`

First, I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Loggers
FROM [alo].[Forests] C
WHERE (R.LogSU = 3)
AND (ForestID REGEXP '106[0-9][3-4]')
```

**This produced an error as below and it would be good to know why.**

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 'REGEXP'.
```

Next, I have tried this, which is now running but I am unsure about whether this is doing what I want it to do.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Loggers
FROM [alo].[Forests] C
WHERE (R.LogSU = 3)
AND (ForestID LIKE '106[0-9][3-4]')
```

**Would this do as I described above?**

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That REGEXP and LIKE behavior is product specific.)

Comment: Which Database? And please add the error that you got.

Comment: Both - done: error and dbms.

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions

Comment: At all? Is there an alternative way to do what I want without listing all the possible number combinations?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PatIndex? Limited regex.

Comment: @DanielShillcock: patindex does not support any regex - at least no according to [the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx): "*pattern
Is a character expression that contains the sequence to be found. Wildcard characters can be used; however, the % character must come before and follow pattern (except when you search for first or last characters).*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to interact with managed code, as you can use [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Loggers
FROM [alo].[Forests] C
WHERE (R.LogSU = 3)
AND ForestID LIKE '106[0-9][3-4]')
```

to make clear: SQL Server doesn't supports regular expressions without managed code. Depending on the situation, the LIKE operator can be an option, but it lacks the flexibility that regular expressions provides.

If you would like to have full regular expression functionality, try [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/).

Comment: So to clarify 1) My second go is correct in specifying 106 followed by any digit followed by a digit that must be either 3 or 4? 2) What do you mean by managed code? Thanks - still very new to SQL

Answer (score 6):

You specify this:

> The pattern I want to capture is 106 followed by any digit followed by
> a digit that must be either 3 or 4, i.e. 106[0-9][3-4]

And then you give an example using a regular expression:

```
WHERE ForestID REGEXP '106[0-9][3-4]'
```

Regular expressions match patterns anywhere inside a string. So, this will match `'10603'`. It will also match `'abc10694 def'`. This is true of regular expressions in general, not merely one databases's implementation of them.

If this is the behavior you want, then the corresponding `LIKE` (in SQL Server)` is:

```
WHERE ForestID LIKE '%106[0-9][3-4]%'
```

If you only want 5-digit values, then the corresponding regular expression is:

```
WHERE ForestID REGEXP '^106[0-9][3-4]$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below

```
SELECT DISTINCT Loggers
FROM [alo].[Forests] C
WHERE (R.LogSU = 3)
AND ((ForestID LIKE '%106_3%' OR ForestID LIKE '%106_4%'))
```